# How to make a UObject-based class which inherits a class that only can be used in UE5 to be compiled both in UE4 and UE5?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am working on a project which should work on both UE4 and UE5. And now I wanna make some blueprint functions which is like Geometry Script. As we all know, UDynamicMesh can only be used on UE5. I tried to use "#if UE_VERSION_OLDER_THAN(5,0,0)" or "#if ENGINE_MAJOR_VERSION == 5" to solve this problem but I find that UCLASS and UFUNCTION can not be inside preprocessor. I have no idea how to make it. Can anyone give some advise? I will be grateful for any help you can provide. My code is here.

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "UDynamicMesh.h"
#include "GeometryScript/GeometryScriptTypes.h"
#include "Kismet/BlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "MyGeometryScriptUtils.generated.h"


/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS(meta = (ScriptName = "GeometryScript_Primitives"))
class MyGEOMETRYPROCESSING_API UMyGeometryScriptUtils : public UBlueprintFunctionLibrary
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "MyGeometryScript", meta=(ScriptMethod))
    static UPARAM(DisplayName = "Target Mesh") UDynamicMesh* 
    Remesh( 
    UDynamicMesh* TargetMesh,
    float TargetTriangleCount = 100.f,
    int32 IterationTimes = 100,
    UGeometryScriptDebug* Debug = nullptr);
    
    
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "MyGeometryScript", meta=(ScriptMethod))
    static UPARAM(DisplayName = "Target Mesh") UDynamicMesh* 
    PlaneUV( 
    UDynamicMesh* TargetMesh,
    const bool bAutoRemap = false,
    const FVector2D InPivot = FVector2D::ZeroVector,
    const float InScale = 1.0f,
    UGeometryScriptDebug* Debug = nullptr);

};
```

I tried to use

```
#if ENGINE_MAJOR_VERSION == 5
```

to make it not to be compiled in UE4.And the code is below.

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "Misc/EngineVersionComparison.h"
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "UDynamicMesh.h"
#include "GeometryScript/GeometryScriptTypes.h"
#include "Kismet/BlueprintFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "MyGeometryScriptUtils.generated.h"


/**
 * 
 */
#if ENGINE_MAJOR_VERSION == 5

UCLASS(meta = (ScriptName = "GeometryScript_Primitives"))
class MyGEOMETRYPROCESSING_API UMyGeometryScriptUtils : public UBlueprintFunctionLibrary
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "MyGeometryScript", meta=(ScriptMethod))
    static UPARAM(DisplayName = "Target Mesh") UDynamicMesh* 
    Remesh( 
        UDynamicMesh* TargetMesh,
        float TargetTriangleCount = 100.f,
        int32 IterationTimes = 100,
        UGeometryScriptDebug* Debug = nullptr);
    
    
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "MyGeometryScript", meta=(ScriptMethod))
    static UPARAM(DisplayName = "Target Mesh") UDynamicMesh* 
    PlaneUV( 
        UDynamicMesh* TargetMesh,
        const bool bAutoRemap = false,
        const FVector2D InPivot = FVector2D::ZeroVector,
        const float InScale = 1.0f,
        UGeometryScriptDebug* Debug = nullptr);

};

#endif
```

But the UHT will give me the error:

```
   UCLASS must not be inside preprocessor blocks, except for WITH_EDITORONLY_DATA
```

---

I think the solution given by Mauro Dorni can solve the above problems. However, I encountered a similar problem and couldn't solve it with his solution. code show as below.

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "GeometryActors/GeneratedDynamicMeshActor.h"
#include "MyGeneratedDynamicMeshActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class MyTest_API AMyGeneratedDynamicMeshActor : public AGeneratedDynamicMeshActor
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()

public:

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite)
    UMySplineComponent* SplineComponent;

    virtual void PostActorCreated() override;

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, CallInEditor, Category="Utils")
    void UpdateActor();
    
protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;
    
public:
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

};
```

The main difference is that the class AGeneratedDynamicMeshActor is only defined in UE5.And if I write code as below, UHT still gives me error.

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once
#include "Misc/EngineVersionComparison.h"
#include "CoreMinimal.h"

#if UE_VERSION_OLDER_THAN(5,0,0)
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#else
#include "GeometryActors/GeneratedDynamicMeshActor.h"
#endif

#include "Manipulator/SplineComponents/MySplineComponent.h"
#include "MyGeneratedDynamicMeshActor.generated.h"


UCLASS()
#if UE_VERSION_OLDER_THAN(5,0,0)
class MyTest_API AMyGeneratedDynamicMeshActor : public AActor
#else
class MyTest_API AMyGeneratedDynamicMeshActor : public AGeneratedDynamicMeshActor
#endif
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite)
    UMySplineComponent* SplineComponent;

    virtual void PostActorCreated() override;

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, CallInEditor, Category="Utils")
    void UpdateActor();
    
protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;
    
public:
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

};
```

The error report is

```
[] Missing 'class' in Class declaration
```

Comment: what about taking in input a generic UObject pointer then cast it in the method body to the right type?

Comment: This solution seems to solve the problem. But I also ran into a similar problem that I can't seem to solve with this one. I added the code to the problem description. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Mh I'm worried about that this one is the same issue, no macro inside a uclass, only with another error message... Can you port your Preproc logic into the cpp file? I'm using macros in my project but all of them are on the implementation side, not declaration

Comment: To extend a bit my comment: declare 2 different classes, one for ue4 and one for ue5, then spawn an entity from code, based on the editor version macro...probably it's not the cleanest way to do that, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating a proxy struct that just stored all the data needed to build my geometry. Since you can wrap that in a macro you can version control it easily. Then just provide either a static library or UObject that can interact with the data appropriately.

IE in ue4 I use the proxy struct to build FDynamicMesh3's but in ue5 i use the same proxy to build UDynamicMesh objects.